# Compare two columns for match or partial match, copy value from third column into fourth column

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

As the title says, I need to compare two columns for a match or partial match and then copy a value from a third column into a fourth column.

A condensed version of my issue below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqQCx.png]

I need to compare the product ID and the supplier product ID (be it match or partial match) then copy the supplier product price into the new product cost column.

I am having limited success with my VLookup formula for matching product ID's as I only know how to do exact matches and not partial matches.

Not every line of the supplier product ID has data in it, nor is the product ID list and the supplier ID list the same length.

The spreadsheet has approximately 2000 products in it.

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

From your description, this formula copied into C3 will work for you.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A3,MID(F3,2,3))),G3, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MID(F3,2,3),A3)),G3, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A3,F3)), G3, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F3,A3)), G3, ""))))
```

I know it looks hard, but its really just testing for equality between the middle of the ID codes, and then if either is just a substring of the other.

It not being vba also means you won't have to make it a macro enabled workbook.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the quick response however this is not working for me. It only returns 0 in spaces where the cell is blank for the supplier ID / price.

Comment: Ahh sorry, this formula would work with the data in your image if you removed the first digit or last digit. I'll give you a new solution in a bit.

Comment: Just to clarify things, the first two rows in your image - are these what most matching cases look like?

Comment: Seldom are they the same. Out of 2000 products I think I had about 39 exact matches when I should be expecting around 250+ partial matches.

It's more a case of the 12346-78 Pink / 12345-67, where someone has added extra text to the product key or the product key is in the product name (which is just another column).

Comment: Now depending on the varying names, the more difficult this problem is going to be. If there is a large difference between the length of the names, then tweaking of this formula will be needed. Just try this code out and see if it performs any better.

Comment: I must be missing something here - this isn't working for me! ):

Comment: I will need some more examples of matching ID's to improve the function then. For your posted image, that formula works. However, Im assuming that your pink ID doesn't match with the product ID in A4. It might even be worth generating a new ID's that follow amore logical pattern that your current (e.g. date + type of product/supplier + iteration in one unique number)

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts today! I believe I have worked out a solution. :)

Comment: If my answer helped you, could you accept it as correct? Glad I could help